# Change the whiteBalanceMode constraint after applying colorTemperature setting in media device

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, camera, webrtc

**Hello everybody!**

Currently, I'm working on the implementation of `colorTemperature` of a project, after the implementation I want to revoke the `colorTemperature` that I applied on it.

I'm able to change the `colorTemperature`, initially the `colorTemperature` is `0` and `whiteBalanceMode` is '`continuous`'. However, after I change the `colorTemperature` to any allowed value, the `whiteBalanceMode` is auto changed to '`manual`'. I cannot reset the `colorTemperature` to `0` again because the value is not allowed, neither can I reset the `whiteBalanceMode` to '`continuous`' again with the similar code that I change `colorTemperature`.

The whole code as followed.

```
'use strict';

const video = document.querySelector('video');
const canvas = window.canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.width = 480;
canvas.height = 360;

const constraints = {
  audio: false,
  video: true,
};

var currTracks = null;

function handleSuccess(stream) {
  const videoTracks = stream.getVideoTracks();
  currTracks = videoTracks;
  window.stream = stream; // make stream available to browser console
  video.srcObject = stream;
}

function handleError(error) {
  console.log('navigator.MediaDevices.getUserMedia error: ', error.message, error.name);
}

async function init(){
  await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(handleSuccess).catch(handleError);
  await changeEnv(currTracks,3600);
  setTimeout(function(){changeEnv(currTracks,5500)},1000);
}

async function changeEnv(tracks,compen) {

  console.log(tracks,performance.now());
  for (const track of tracks) {
    console.log('curr',track.getSettings());
    console.log('capab',track.getCapabilities());
    if (compen === 3600) {
      await track.applyConstraints({advanced:[{colorTemperature: compen}]});
    } else {
      await track.applyConstraints({advanced:[{whiteBalanceMode: 'continuous'}]});
    }
    console.log('curr',track.getSettings());
  } 
}
init();
```

Which I can call `track.getCapabilities()` on to get the capabilities.

```
{
    aspectRatio: {max: 4000, min: 0.0003333333333333333},
    colorTemperature: {max: 7000, min: 2850, step: 50},
    deviceId: "332d34c91861f97ba8f0e11f446da4566a1803539764dd67c1dfe036ef32fd97",
    exposureCompensation: {max: 2, min: -2, step: 0.10000000149011612},
    exposureMode: (2) ["continuous", "manual"],
    exposureTime: {max: 1250, min: 0, step: 0},
    facingMode: ["environment"],
    focusMode: (3) ["manual", "single-shot", "continuous"],
    frameRate: {max: 30, min: 0},
    groupId: "40f2953f5fae495c7471348c844e919762a3213019b271664d220d0aa617313c",
    height: {max: 3000, min: 1},
    iso: {max: 4000, min: 20, step: 1},
    resizeMode: (2) ["none", "crop-and-scale"],
    torch: true,
    whiteBalanceMode: (2) ["continuous", "manual"],
    width: {max: 4000, min: 1}
}
```

> Copied from the Chromium console log.

*Does anybody know how to change the `whiteBalanceMode` constraint to change back the device to continuous mode?*

Answer (score 0):

colorTemperature min is listed as 2850. It cannot be set to 0.

Also I referred the following links:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackConstraints
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/applyConstraints

From reading MDN it seems you can reset constraints to defaults if you provide no value. Providing constraints is optional. If constraints are reset then whitebalance should also reset.

I tried your script on brave browser, but it just shows 4500 color temperature and doesn't change its value to 3600.

Comment: yea i also tried on pc again, the value cannnot be changed, on mobile browser the color temperature value is able to be changed